# Change Minimum Level of Logging in SeriLog using appsettings.json

Tags: c#, serilog

Is there a way to do this?
I would like to change the minimum level of logging by reading the setting off the appsettings.json

My code looks like this

```
            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", applicationName)
                .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), "logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you read the docs?

Comment: I know how to read the value off of the appsettings.json file - but i am unsure how to pass it in, since it is not an enum

Comment: This should have everything you need. https://nblumhardt.com/2016/03/reading-logger-configuration-from-appsettings-json/

Comment: Show us what you've tried :)

Comment: I used this code to get the applicationName:

Comment: IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"));

   var root = builder.Build();
   var applicationName = root.GetSection("Application").Value;

Comment: But I think the comment by Mr. T might be on to something, I can load the entire file instead of using code to configure it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this by using appsettings.json to define serilog settings and also using code to add a WriteTo method (I needed to do this in code because I am passing the renderMessage parameter to the constructor of JsonFormatter.

Here is what my appsettings.json looks like:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample Application"
    }
  },
  "LogsFilePath": "logs/myapp.txt",
  "LogsRollingInterval": "Day"
```

And in my code I did this:

```
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"));

            var config = builder.Build();

            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true),
                    config.GetSection("LogsFilePath").Value,
                    rollingInterval: (RollingInterval)Enum.Parse(typeof(RollingInterval), config.GetSection("LogsRollingInterval").Value))
                .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code to configure it using appsettings.json in .net core

```
return new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(path: _configuration.GetValue(Constants.SerilogFileConfigurations.Path, "Logs\\Log_.txt")!,
                    outputTemplate: _configuration.GetValue(Constants.SerilogFileConfigurations.OutputTemplate, defaultOutputTemplate)!,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: _configuration.GetValue(Constants.SerilogFileConfigurations.RetainedFileCountLimit, 5)!,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Enum.TryParse(typeof(LogEventLevel), _configuration.GetValue(Constants.SerilogFileConfigurations.LogLevel, "Information"), out object? logLevel)
                        ? (LogEventLevel)logLevel! : LogEventLevel.Information,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .MinimumLevel.Debug();
```